# SQL Wildcard for numbers divided by |

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, wildcard

I have data saved in one field like this: 1|3, or 1, or 1|7|12. What I need is WHERE condition, which finds out whether my number is there or not. Also if my variable "number" is not present, I have to return all results. I tried this, but seems like it's not working.

```
Field LIKE '%number%' AND Field NOT LIKE '_number%'
```

Comment: You shouldn't have stored the numbers like that in the first place....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you should put those numbers in a separate table if you want to make an efficient query. Matching part of a field can't use any index, so it won't scale well.

If you can't do that, you would check for the value surrounded by the separators, so you have to add separators before and after the field value to make an exact match:

```
where '|' + Field + '|' like '%|' + @number + '|%'
```

Comment: This wouldn't help returning the whole string in the case no match was found. In this case it would exclude the row.

Comment: Looks good, but it returns this, when number is set: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%|' to data type int." Where could be the problem?

Comment: @JacobH: If you have a numeric value you need to cast it to `varchar` to concatenate it with the strings: `'%|' + cast(@number as varhcar) + '|%'`.

Comment: Okay maybe one last thing. Now it's not working when number is empty. It says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'." It is beacuse there is cast( as varhcar). If I will add some number there, it won't select all values like I wanted.

Comment: @JacobH: If the number is not a number but an empty string, you will get a syntax error as the code becomes `cast( as varchar)`. If you don't have a number at all, you should exclude the entire `where` clause instead of constructing one that has no effect.

Comment: I have default 0 there and now how can I get all results to this query? If I use "OR Filed LIKE ''" it always returns all results.

Comment: Okay, but I cannot edit anything else than where clause, cms I use does not allow it to me.

Comment: @JacobH: If you need the entire condition, then add `or 'nunber' = '0'` to make the default select all, or if possible use `1=1` as the entire condition if you don't have any number.

Comment: Yes but it returns all result always :( Here is whole my where condition, what am I missing here? " ('|' + field + '|' LIKE '%|' + cast(number as varchar) + '|%' OR 1=1) "

Comment: @JacobH: Use `1=1` as the entire condition, i.e. `where 1 = 1` when you don't have a number, and `where '|' + field + '|' like '|42|'` when you have the number 42. Alternatively with a default of 0 use `where '|' + field + '|' like '|0|' or 0 = 0` when you don't have a number and `where '|' + field + '|' like '|42|' or 42 = 0` when you have the number 42.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when (Field LIKE '%|' + cast(number as varchar(32)) + '|%' or Field LIKE cast(number as varchar(32)) + '|%' or Field LIKE '%|' + cast(number as varchar(32)) or cast(number as varchar(32)) = Field) then cast(number as varchar(32)) else Field end)
    from ...
```

Comment: That would not find anything in single numbers, e.g. `1` in `1`.

Comment: All three conditions require that there is at least one `|` character in the field, so it would never find anything if the field contains for example `1`.